# Gmail API: 400 bad request when trying to send an email (PHP code)

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api

I expected the code below to send an email, but I'm only getting this:

> An error occurred: Error calling POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send: (400) Bad
>   Request

I get a `200 OK` using the Google Developers Console [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send?hl=es) at the bottom. Any help?

```
$client_id = '599901532082-js1r50n20q6n5mir9fo1g81qkj9kfn3j.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$service_account_name = '599901532082-js1r50n20q6n5mir9fo1g81qkj9kfn3j@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = '/tmp/APIProject-cb6558ba6435.p12';

$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$service = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);  

if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
  $service_account_name,
  array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'),
  $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
//check if you want the validity of this string at: http://www.komeil.com/toolbox/base64decoder
//it is web safe base64 encoded email
$mime = "RnJvbTogSm9obiBEb2UgPHRpcmVuZ2FyZmlvQGdtYWlsLmVzPiANClRvOiBNYXJ5IFNtaXRoIDx0aXJlbmdhcmZpb0BnbWFpbC5jb20-IA0KU3ViamVjdDogU2F5aW5nIEhlbGxvIA0KRGF0ZTogRnJpLCAyMSBOb3YgMTk5NyAwOTo1NTowNiAtMDYwMCANCk1lc3NhZ2UtSUQ6IDwxMjM0QGxvY2FsLm1hY2hpbmUuZXhhbXBsZT4NCg0KVGhpcyBpcyBhIG1lc3NhZ2UganVzdCB0byBzYXkgaGVsbG8uIFNvLCAiSGVsbG8iLg==";


$service = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);

$msg = new \Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$msg->setRaw($mime);

try {
  $results = $service->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
  print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . ' sent.';
  return $message;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();

}
```

**EDIT:**

this is the request object. It includes the response data also:

```
object(Google_Http_Request)[508]
  private 'batchHeaders' => 
    array (size=3)
      'Content-Type' => string 'application/http' (length=16)
      'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => string 'binary' (length=6)
      'MIME-Version' => string '1.0' (length=3)
  protected 'queryParams' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'requestMethod' => string 'POST' (length=4)
  protected 'requestHeaders' => 
    array (size=3)
      'content-type' => string 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' (length=31)
      'authorization' => string 'Bearer ya29.8gEUMiBLfxS8OLdSmpiQ-EcumeATo2qFAfPtPqwTw9fQ2zVrfZaA1X5OLoBmQccrXr8V8g' (length=82)
      'accept-encoding' => string 'gzip' (length=4)
  protected 'baseComponent' => string 'https://www.googleapis.com' (length=26)
  protected 'path' => string '/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send' (length=32)
  protected 'postBody' => string '{"raw":"RnJvbTogSm9obiBEb2UgPHRpcmVuZ2FyZmlvQGdtYWlsLmVzPg0KVG86IE1hcnkgU21pdGggPHRpcmVuZ2FyZmlvQGdtYWlsLmNvbT4NClN1YmplY3Q6IFNheWluZyBIZWxsbw0KDQpUaGlzIGlzIGEgbWVzc2FnZSBqdXN0IHRvIHNheSBoZWxsby4gU28sICdIZWxsbycu"}' (length=214)
  protected 'userAgent' => string 'Client_Library_Examples google-api-php-client/1.0.6-beta (gzip)' (length=63)
  protected 'canGzip' => boolean true
  protected 'responseHttpCode' => null
  protected 'responseHeaders' => null
  protected 'responseBody' => null
  protected 'expectedClass' => string 'Google_Service_Gmail_Message' (length=28)
  public 'accessKey' => null

object(Google_Http_Request)[508]
  private 'batchHeaders' => 
    array (size=3)
      'Content-Type' => string 'application/http' (length=16)
      'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => string 'binary' (length=6)
      'MIME-Version' => string '1.0' (length=3)
  protected 'queryParams' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'requestMethod' => string 'POST' (length=4)
  protected 'requestHeaders' => 
    array (size=4)
      'content-type' => string 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' (length=31)
      'authorization' => string 'Bearer ya29.8gEUM***fxS8OLdSmpiQ-EcumeATo2qFAfPtPqwTw9fQ2zVrfZaA1X5OLoBmQccrXr8V8g' (length=82)
      'accept-encoding' => string 'gzip' (length=4)
      'content-length' => int 214
  protected 'baseComponent' => string 'https://www.googleapis.com' (length=26)
  protected 'path' => string '/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send' (length=32)
  protected 'postBody' => string '{"raw":"RnJvbTogSm9obiBEb2UgPHRpcmVuZ2FyZmlvQGdtYWlsLmVzPg0KVG86IE1hcnkgU21pdGggPHRpcmVuZ2FyZmlvQGdtYWlsLmNvbT4NClN1YmplY3Q6IFNheWluZyBIZWxsbw0KDQpUaGlzIGlzIGEgbWVzc2FnZSBqdXN0IHRvIHNheSBoZWxsby4gU28sICdIZWxsbycu"}' (length=214)
  protected 'userAgent' => string 'Client_Library_Examples google-api-php-client/1.0.6-beta (gzip)' (length=63)
  protected 'canGzip' => boolean true
  protected 'responseHttpCode' => int 400
  protected 'responseHeaders' => 
    array (size=13)
      'vary' => string 'Origin
X-Origin' (length=15)
      'content-type' => string 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' (length=31)
      'content-encoding' => string 'gzip' (length=4)
      'date' => string 'Fri, 18 Sep 2015 08:34:25 GMT' (length=29)
      'expires' => string 'Fri, 18 Sep 2015 08:34:25 GMT' (length=29)
      'cache-control' => string 'private, max-age=0' (length=18)
      'x-content-type-options' => string 'nosniff' (length=7)
      'x-frame-options' => string 'SAMEORIGIN' (length=10)
      'x-xss-protection' => string '1; mode=block' (length=13)
      'server' => string 'GSE' (length=3)
      'alternate-protocol' => string '443:quic,p=1' (length=12)
      'alt-svc' => string 'quic=":443"; p="1"; ma=604800' (length=29)
      'transfer-encoding' => string 'chunked' (length=7)
  protected 'responseBody' => string '{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "failedPrecondition",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
' (length=179)
  protected 'expectedClass' => string 'Google_Service_Gmail_Message' (length=28)
  public 'accessKey' => null
```

Comment: Should you really supply the `Date` and `Message-ID` headers when you send a mail? Try this instead: `"RnJvbTogSm9obiBEb2UgPHRpcmVuZ2FyZmlvQGdtYWlsLmVzPgpUbzogTWFyeSBTbWl0aCA8dGlyZW5nYXJmaW9AZ21haWwuY29tPgpTdWJqZWN0OiBTYXlpbmcgSGVsbG8KClRoaXMgaXMgYSBtZXNzYWdlIGp1c3QgdG8gc2F5IGhlbGxvLiBTbywgJ0hlbGxvJy4="`

Comment: @Tholle thanks, but the error message is the same..

Comment: Do you have any way of displaying the low level http `POST`-request with fiddler or something similar?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

finally got to send Mails with your code:

I think you have misunderstood the GMail API a little bit.

To use it, you must authenticate to the API. To do this, there are two ways:

- use OAuth - the Server redirects the user to google's servers, where they can login, grant permission to your app, and pass a token back to you
- Service Accounts. These are a little bit more complicated:

  - First, you'll have to setup an app (done)
  - second, you'll have to setup a service account. This is how your app authenticates to google. you've done that, and the certificate you've got contains the private key to authenticate
  - third, the user needs to grant your application access to act on behalf of them. This is the point you haven't done yet.

So what you're currently trying is to send mails from the service account, but this is *not* an GMail Account.

The Developer Console uses the OAuth method, so there's no problem to try this.

Please also note: With regular GMail Accounts, you can *not* use 'Service Accounts'. You'll have to use OAuth.
To use Service Accounts, you need to be a Google Apps customer.

I won't conver OAuth authorization here, because it's completely different, and there are *many* examples out there.

To grant your Service Account Permissions to send mails on behalf of your GMails/Google Apps accounts, please follow
[this document](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes). For `One or More API Scopes`, you'll have to enter
`https://mail.google.com/,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send`.

After you've setup this, it's possible to send mails, just modify the code as follows:

```
$results = $service->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
```

won't work, because 'me' referrs to the service account, which can't send mail (see above).
Replace `me` with the user id (mail-address) of the account from which the mails should be send.:

```
$results = $service->users_messages->send("senders_mail@domain.com", $msg);
```

Then, you'll need to add

```
$cred->sub = 'senders_mail@domain.com';
```

below

```
$cred = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
  $service_account_name,
  array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'),
  $key
);
```

Please also note that `$message` should be `$msg` in the `try...catch`-Block.

Below, you'll find the the complete, working code for me:

```
<?php
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../src/Google/autoload.php');
$client_id = '*censored*.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$service_account_name = '*censored*@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$key_file_location = '/tmp/apiKey.p12';


$userid_from='*censored*';
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");


//hmmm, really don't know whether these lines are necessary
if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}

$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
  $service_account_name,
  array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'),
  $key
);
$cred->sub=$userid_from; //<-- Important!
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

//check if you want the validity of this string at: http://www.komeil.com/toolbox/base64decoder
//it is web safe base64 encoded email
$mime = "*censored*, same content as you posted, but another recipient ;-)";


$service = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);

$msg = new \Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$msg->setRaw($mime);

try {
  $results = $service->users_messages->send($userid_from, $msg);
  print 'Message with ID: ' . $results->id . ' sent.';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

If there are any questions left, feel free to ask!

Comment: I did everything exactly as you described but still get a 400 error :( I specified `sub` and granted domain-wide access to my service-account (but without `gmail.modify`-scope, this should be no problem right).. Do you have any idea? Please help! Thanks in advance

Comment: I just saw you are doing `$service = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);` twice. Just by accident or with any reason?

Comment: @wottpal seems like an accident, yes. I'll check tomorrow, if you don't get your problem solved till then, i can try to help you (in chat)

Answer (score 3):

One thing that I needed to get my service account client working that wasn't obvious was adding this:

```
// you MUST do this to avoid 400 error
$user_to_impersonate = 'junk@example.net';
$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);
```

Comment: What do you mean by setting a subject on the client which doesn't even implement `setSubject`?

Comment: well, my version of the api did support setSubject.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are forgetting to assign the `$client_id` to your `$client` variable.

```
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setApplicationName('Gmail API test');
$client->setDeveloperKey('<YOUR_API_KEY>');
$client->setClientSecret('<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>');
$client->SetClientId('599901532082-js1r50n20q6n5mir9fo1g81qkj9kfn3j.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'));
$client->setAccessToken('{"access_token":"<YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN>",
                          "token_type":"Bearer"‌​,"expires_in":3600,
                          "refresh_token":"<YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN>","created":12344556}');

$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

$raw = "RnJvbTogSm9obiBEb2UgPHRpcmVuZ2FyZmlvQGdtYWlsLmVzPiANClRvOiBNYXJ5IFNtaXRoIDx0aXJlbmdhcmZpb0BnbWFpbC5jb20-IA0KU3ViamVjdDogU2F5aW5nIEhlbGxvIA0KRGF0ZTogRnJpLCAyMSBOb3YgMTk5NyAwOTo1NTowNiAtMDYwMCANCk1lc3NhZ2UtSUQ6IDwxMjM0QGxvY2FsLm1hY2hpbmUuZXhhbXBsZT4NCg0KVGhpcyBpcyBhIG1lc3NhZ2UganVzdCB0byBzYXkgaGVsbG8uIFNvLCAiSGVsbG8iLg==";

$msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$msg->setRaw($raw);

$results = $service->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . ' sent.';
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a **full working example**, just make sure to change all the appropriate info and use **PHPMailer** to format a valid mail.

```
<?php

// this the link to gmail-api-client or whatever you have...
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// download PHPMailer
// https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer and uncomment the line below.
// require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

define('FROM', 'aseptik@gmail.com'); //email of sender
define('TO', 'XXXXXXX@XXXXX.com');//email of receiver

$client_email = 'XXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
$private_key = file_get_contents('tmp/XXXXXXX.p12');
$scopes = array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose'
);

$credentials = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($client_email, $scopes, $private_key);

$credentials->sub = FROM;

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}

function create_message() {
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->setFrom(FROM, 'John Doe 1');
    $mail->addAddress(TO, 'John Doe 2');
    $mail->Subject = 'Saying Hello';
    $mail->Body = 'This is a message just to say hello. So, "Hello"';
    $mail->preSend();
    $mime = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
    return urlsafe_b64encode($mime);
}

function sendMessage($service, $userId, $message) {
    try {
        $message = $service->users_messages->send($userId, $message);
        print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . ' sent.';
        return $message;
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

function urlsafe_b64encode($string) {
    $data = base64_encode($string);
    $data = str_replace(array('+','/','=') , array('-','_','') , $data);
    return $data;
}

$service = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);

$msg = new \Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
$msg->setRaw(create_message());

sendMessage($service, 'me', $msg);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use URL Endocde in string and url.

This error is space in url.

Comment: I have encoded the email. Loot at "check if you want the validity". What else should I encode exactly? what url do you mean? could you paste some code?