# Google API (Gmail) failing with failed precondition 400

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-identity

I am trying to use the google APIs to read emails and I'm repeatedly failing to get good results. It is supposed to be a server->server account that runs periodically in the background, but I can't get it to connect. The code is basic:

```
GoogleCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream("Content/service_credential.json", FileMode.Open, 
                                   FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
    credential = credential.CreateScoped(new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailModify });
}

var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "try-apis",
});


ListLabelsResponse response = service.Users.Labels.List("me").Execute();
foreach (Label label in response.Labels.OrderBy(p => p.Name))
{
    Console.WriteLine(label.Id + " - " + label.Name);
}

Console.Read();
```

Error:

```
Additional information: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError

Bad Request [400]

Errors [

    Message[Bad Request] Location[ - ] Reason[failedPrecondition] Domain[global]

]
```

In IAM settings, the account I'm using has full permissions:

[image]

The account has full permissions:

[image]

Likewise, more full permissions:

[image]

What am I missing? I can't find any representative .Net requests that make sense in just connecting to an in box.

Comment: Based from this [blog](http://techathlon.com/fix-bad-request-error-400-gmail-google-chrome/), you might have encountered the Bad Request Error 400 if you are signed into multiple Google account for Gmail using Chrome. From this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591549/gmail-api-400-bad-request-when-trying-to-send-an-email-php-code), maybe you have problem with the authentication. Check this related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29327846/gmail-rest-api-400-bad-request-failed-precondition

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. XLSX documents uploaded into Google Drive (Sheets) do not support Google Sheets API. Copying the data into a sheet created directly in Google Sheets resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a way in IAM to grant domain-wide delegation before.

Typically the developer ID is whitelisted in the domain CPanel like [described in these docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority).

(The paragraph that says "Then an administrator of the Google Apps domain must complete the following steps".)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the user that you want to get messages for. In your case, it'd look like this:

```
credential = GoogleCredential
                .FromStream(stream)
                .CreateScoped(new[]{ GmailService.Scope.GmailModify })**
                .CreateWithUser("me") **;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used ***Service Account*** and I did not authorize my service/application to **access user data** on behalf of users in my case when I saw the same error. If it is your case, see

a) [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) if you use the private domain and have Google admin access.

b) Generate and store [refresh token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) to access the user's account (through access token).