# Laravel 5.2 sending emails created by swift_message via oriceon/oauth-5-laravel

Tags: php, oauth, laravel-5, gmail-api, swiftmailer

As shown in my attempts belowbelow I am trying to use Laravel 5.2 with [oriceon/oauth-5-laravel package](https://github.com/oriceon/oauth-5-laravel) to authorize a user on my website and then allow that user to send a email to someone else thruough their own account via my website.

```
Attempt:1 using laravels inbuilt swift_message(note emails are just examples)
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject("Test Email");
$message->setFrom("dukeforsythtester@gmail.com");
$message->setTo("tester@gmail.com");
$message->setReplyTo("dukeforsythtester@gmail.com");
$message->setBody("This is a test of adding a body!");
$to_send = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($message->toString()), '+/', '-_'),'=');
$result = $googleService->request('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send',$to_send);


Attempt 2: using imap_mail_compose via php natively
$envelope["from"]= "dukeforsythtester@gmail.com"; 
$envelope["to"]  = "dukeforsyth@outlook.com";
$envelope["subject"]  = "Testing...";
$part1["type"] = TYPETEXT;
$part1["subtype"] = "plain";
$part1["description"] = "description3";
$part1["contents.data"] = "contents.data3\n\n\n\t";

$body[1] = $part1;

$mime = imap_mail_compose ($envelope , $body);
$mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($mime), '+/', '-_'), '=');
$result = $googleService->request('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send',$mime);
```

Either way I have the response of:

```
TokenResponseException in StreamClient.php line 68:
Failed to request resource. HTTP Code: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

I believe I have the correct scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send' for sending emails for the user after they authorize it. I also made sure that the from address is the authorized users email address, but I am unsure if I am just doing something silly or missing something in the encoding.

Any help would greatly be appreciated, been stuck on this for two days now!

Comment: You might want to check how you've composed your request. Having an error 400 : Bad Request may be due to wrong request format, insufficient required parameter passed to the Google Server. You might want to check this related SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32667951/5995040) that discussed how authentication can may the request return an error 400. For some code implementation, you might want to check the [PHP QuickStart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php) by Google. Hope this helps.

Comment: Like you have said this is a malformed request. 
What I need to know more so is what is the format for the proper request, as in the documentations that are here [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) where it states that in the post request I need to pass a Users.messages resource. 
From what I saw in the documentation this looked like a json object with the correct parameters. I tried to mimic this example from the link as shown above but I am unsure if I have to set the id's and such manually.

Comment: I have a working solution! posting here just incase someone ever runs into this issue or something similar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution using Laravel 5.2 with oriceon/oauth-5-laravel package along with google's google/apiclient package to send the actual message. Big thanks to  @Mr.Rebot for the guidance!

```
    $code = Input::get('code');
    $googleService = \OAuth::consumer('Google');
    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if ( ! is_null($code) ) 
    { 
        // Variables
        $redirect_uri = 'your redirect url that is set on google console';
        $user_to_impersonate = 'dukeforsythtester@gmail.com';
        // Create client with these set credentials
        $client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig('path to your json given by google console');
        $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
        $client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);
        $scopes = [ \Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_SEND ];
        $client->setScopes($scopes);

        $token = $client->authenticate($code);
        $client->setAccessToken($token);        
        if( $client->isAccessTokenExpired() )
        {
            // need to refresh token
            $refreshToken = $client->refreshToken($token);
            $client->setAccessToken($refreshToken);

        }

        // Create the service
        $service = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);

        // Create the message
        $msg = new \Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
        $msg->setRaw($this->create_message());

        // Send off the message
        $this->sendMessage($service, 'me', $msg);
    }
    else {
        // Get googleService authorization
        $url = $googleService->getAuthorizationUri();
        // return to google login url
        return redirect((string)$url);
    }
```