# Error 400 Failed Precondition server side gmail api php

Tags: php, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

hi im trying to get a list of my email using gmail api with php but i got error 400, is PHP for Gmail API is still developed or just im doin it wrong ?

```
$optParams = [];
    $optParams['maxResults'] = 5; // Return Only 5 Messages
    $optParams['labelIds'] = 'INBOX'; // Only show messages in Inbox
    $optParams['q'] = 'from: "abc"'; // Only show messages in Inbox
    $list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages("my email",$optParams);
```

btw i'm non g suite and using service account
Thanks

--- update ---

Here's my $gmail variable source

```
 putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.base_path('service_account.json'));
   $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->setScopes(\Google_Service_Gmail::MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');        // offline access
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $gmail = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);
```

Comment: Gmail api is working fine (I checked before commenting here). Are you sure you have the correct authorization ? with the right scopes ? Try removing `q` parameter (in the case where the filter is not written the way it should). How do you create your `$gmail` service ? Are you trying to access your own account emails, or is it somebody's emails ? In that latter case, it should have been authorized with the appropriate process

Comment: You're doing it wrong. possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591549/gmail-api-400-bad-request-when-trying-to-send-an-email-php-code

Comment: @ pierre im update my answer above

Comment: @noogui okay im gonna check it